# Pagination with Yii

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I have some experience with Yii from an year ago, but I cannot solve this simple task for a website I have to take over as developer;

I have the following (very simplified):

**CONTROLLER**

```
$data = $this->webshop->$funcname($_POST['fromDate'],$_POST['toDate'],$_POST['category']);
//this may contain thousands of rows

$this->render('index', array(
    'model' => $this->oStatForm,
    'data' => $data,
    'sum' => $sum,
));
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="gridview" id="stat_grid">
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('table',array('data'=>$data)); ?>
</div>
```

and in the table there is a `foreach` which prints the table rows. I have to implement pagination in the whole thing... but I have no idea how to do this, since POST is used. CLinkPager was my first try, but it works with GET...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using [CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) with [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) and all pagination, filtering, etc. will be done automatically.

Comment: Will give it a try tomorrow. 10x!